# How to develop an Application so that other people are able to create extensions/plugins for it

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, plugins

I've just finished reading this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972962.aspx 
and search a lot, yet i don't understand how to develop an Application that is "Plug-In Ready"

How does one develop an application that exposes its information/data to a plug-In so that the plugin can manipulate said data.

Eg. Plugins I have downloaded for Visual Studio, for example "regExp", can modify the editor's data (ie, the source code).

How does one develop such an application - is their a design pattern or framework (`IPlugin` from .Net perhaps?)

All the info/help is appreciated

Aiden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you "reverse" your thinking and say that it's the plugin that exposes *its* properties and methods, it might be easier to understand.

In .Net you can define an `Interface` to define which method and properties that should be implemented. An interface doesn't do much on its own, just defining these things.

This enables the main program to dynamically load this plugin in form of a dll and check if the interface is implemented. If it is the main program now what method to call by the use invoke as they are exposed by the dll/library. The dll itself knows nothing about the main program at this stage.

In your plugin you then have a method that can take a parameter to get data from the main program (text or anything else). So when the main program do a call on the plugin it provides the information at the same time. The data can be a class holding different type of data again - this way a plugin could access the data of the main application as it is provided to it.

.Net also offer a plugin system called MEF (Managed Extensibility Framework) from .net 4+. See more information on that here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167321/MEF-with-ASP-NET-Hello-World